# OpenXPKI with JSCEP to renew certificate

Tags: ca

I have a Cert mgmt component which allows `cert enrollment` on `OPENXPKI` and `MS CA`.

The module gets the `CSR` as an input, signs the CSR using a `signer on behalf`/`trusted certificate` and then get it signed by target `CA`.

This works fine for both `MS CA` and `OPENXPKI`. When I'm trying to **renew the certificate** using the same `CSR`, it is working on `MS CA`. But, for `OPENXPKI`, `CA` is returning back the existing cert, instead of renewing the cert with the new validity period.

If I create a new `CSR` with the same subject identity, using a new key pair, getting the certificate renewed. Meaning, the `CSR` should be created with a new key pair to get it renewed on `OPENXPKI`.

I got stuck as I can't change my input which is essentially the same CSR which was used for enrollment. Can anyone suggest me any `workflow/configuration` which can allow me to get the cert renewed with same `CSR`, on `OPENXPKI`?

Please note that I'm constrained by the fact that I have to use `SCEP` only to get the `certificate enrolled/renewed`.